# Testing and Continuous Integration

Tags: reactjs, testing, continuous-integration

I am new to React and was also learning testing as well as continuous integration and its importance. You know, I have read a lot of articles on the topic of testing and CI and majority of them say that "both are very important":) and but really want you to confirm if my understanding is correct. So, firstly, concerning testing, is it true that we write tests in software development to ensure that we keep our application under control, that is, if we add new feature to the app then we run tests to ensure whether we break something or not. Again, we make changes to the app then run tests to ensure whether we brake something or not? Secondly, concerning Continuous integration, is it true that CI is needed so that we do not manually run tests, that is, we do not need to type npm run tests or we can forget to run tests before pushing to github thus CI runs tests for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Testing locally and running tests in CI are fulfilling the same goal which is to achieve the greatest quality. 
  You should always run tests locally (you don't want to commit broken code), and some people will even advocate you should make a habit out of it, i.e always use any possible way to help you committing only working code. I suggest for instance to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_craftsmanship
- About CI, assuming you are maintaining a test suite and the CI server is instructed to run them against your code, then of course that should be enough for the CI server to prevent non working code from reaching production. 
  However it would be a real waste of time and resources, thus also a very bad habit, to rely only on the CI server to run the test suite, as it would mean you have no idea if you code works before you commit it and it means you're ready to take a lot of risks about quality.

As much as possible, only working code should be committed. It's especially important when working in teams. 
Thus you should always validate the quality of your work without depending on external server.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer. Just two questions. Firstly, is it true that after we made changes to code base then we run tests TO CHECK IF CHANGES WE MADE BROKE SOMETHING? Secondly, if we need to run tests manually to commit only working code, then WHY DO WE NEED TO HAVE CI TO RUN TESTS AGAIN in the server since we ALREADY pushed working code?

Comment: @MII a correctly setup CI server should run your tests in a fresh and isolated environment, which is cleaner than testing always on your local environment. Your local environment is not always in a predicable state, also even when you might run your tests successfully, you could forget to commit all the files required for those tests, thus the CI server is needed to prevent such mistakes. Finally, when you work in a team, several people will commit different modules and changes that might conflict with the quality of your own code, which is why a CI server matters even if you push working code

Comment: ok great, sorry but please can you give your kind reply for my first question as well? which is "is it true that after we made changes to code base then we run tests TO CHECK IF CHANGES WE MADE BROKE SOMETHING"? That is,  tests helps us be sure that the made changes did not break our code base. Right?

Comment: please I really need your help just my last question(((

Comment: * Yes it's a good practice to run tests on your codebase after changes. 
* Yes the tests will help to ensure there is no regression
Also : 
* if you touch/add code for which there is no test, it's highly recommended to write tests for this code, to reduce the probability to cause regression in the future.